# 2-cohomology group of complex compact algebraic surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

I'm looking at the proof in Griffith Harris of the following fact:let $S$ be a compact algebraic complex surface such that its Betti numbers are equal to that of $\mathbb{P}^2$ and whose canonical bundle is not positive.

Then $S$ is biholomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2$. At the beginning of the proof, they say that $H^1(S,\mathcal{O}_S)$ vanish(which depends on the cohomological condition) and then they say so $Pic(M) \cong H^2(S,\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

The fact I'm struggling to understand is the last isomorphism: from the cohomological conditions we just know that the rank of the $H^2(S;\mathbb{Z})$ is one, but it's looking like there obviously should be no torsion (which I do not see why).

Comment: I don't have GH in front of me, but I can imagine a proof that proceeds as follows: since $Pic(S)$ has rank 1, some multiple $mK_S$ of the canonical must be a very ample divisor, and since $K_S$ is not positive, that  $m$ must be negative; hence $S$ is del Pezzo, but the only smooth del Pezzo with $H^2$ of rank 1 is the projective plane. Note that this proof doesn't really need that $Pic$ is torsion-free.

Comment: On the other hand, it does use classification of del Pezzo surfaces, which may be overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem important for G-H's argument that $H^2(S,\mathbb{Z})$ is torsion-free, but here is a proof anyway:

By the universal coefficient theorem, there is a short exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow \text{Ext}^1(H_1(S,\mathbb{Z}), \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H^2(S,\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \text{Hom}(H_2(S,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow 0$$
To see that $H^2(S,\mathbb{Z})$ is torsion-free it is therefore sufficient to show that $H_1(S,\mathbb{Z})=0$; since $H_1(S,\mathbb{Z})$ is a quotient of $\pi_1(S)$, it suffices to show that $S$ has no nontrivial finite covering spaces $\tilde{S}$.

Such an $\tilde{S}$ would satisfy $$\chi(\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{S}}) = d\chi(\mathcal{O}_{S}) = d$$

where $d$ denotes the degree of $f:\tilde{S} \rightarrow S$. The equality $d=1$ then follows from the equalities $h^{0,1}=h^{0,2}=0$; in turn, these latter equalities follow from Kodaira vanishing if $-K_{\tilde{S}}$ is ample. But the argument of Lazzaro Campeotti in the comments shows that $-K_S$ is ample, and so $-K_{\tilde{S}}=-f^*K_S$ is also ample.